# How to re-enable sysvinit on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, sysvinit

So we had a couple of Arch guys hack a Debian install up for an embedded system (that is no longer so embedded) and they disabled Sysvinit in favour of using multiple linked `/etc/rc.*` files.  Unfortunately I can't do a fresh install at this point in time which would be much preferred but I am guessing it would less effort to re-enable Sysvinit.

I can see that Sysvinit is still installed, but I can't find the method by which booting would be handed off to it.  `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` offers no clues.  There is a `/boot/kexec.sh` file with the following in it:

```
kexec vmlinuz --command-line="root=/dev/sda5 \
init=/sbin/init \
console=ttyS0,38400n8f elevator=deadline" -f
```

With a commented out line:

```
# kexec vmlinuz --command-line="root=/dev/sda5 \
# loglevel=0 console=ttyS0,38400n8 init=/etc/rc.start irqpoll" -f
```

But I'm not even sure if kexec.sh gets loaded or not...

So how can I get Sysvinit running again so it boots using the `rc[0-6].d`  folders?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** inittab looks like this: https://gist.github.com/hamstar/6161321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in your `/etc/inittab`?

Since your `init=` value is point at init, that is the program that is first ran when the system boots.  The traditional init, uses the `/etc/inittab` to configure what happens next.  Your inittab will look something like this on a stock Debian setup.

```
# The default runlevel.
id:2:initdefault:
# Boot-time system configuration/initialization script.
# This is run first except when booting in emergency (-b) mode.
si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
# /etc/init.d executes the S and K scripts upon change
# of runlevel.
#
# Runlevel 0 is halt.
# Runlevel 1 is single-user.
# Runlevels 2-5 are multi-user.
l0:0:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 0
l1:1:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 1
l2:2:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 2
```

The output of `/proc/cmdline` would also confirm what boot parameters are being passed to the kernel.

Comment: Oh yea, why didn't I just at a stock one... `/proc/cmdline` does show /sbin/init and I can see what to change in `/etc/inittab` now.  Thanks a lot!!! :D

Comment: This is what my `inittab` looks like if you were interested too: https://gist.github.com/hamstar/6161321